# What happens when a Task is run but finishes after the HTTP response is returned?

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous, async-await, task, .net-4.7.2

I found this (simplified) action method in an ASP.NET project:

```
    [Route("")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get()
    {  
        // other await calls here...
        StartReportGenerationInBackground();
        return CreateReportRedirectResponse();
    }

    private void StartReportGenerationInBackground()
    {
        // GENERATE Report in background worker
        new Task(async () => // concern with this new thread is that IIS could kill the process given the response will have already been returned.
        {
            var fileResult = await GetReportBytesAsync();
        }).Start();
    }
    
    private async Task<FileResult> GetReportBytesAsync()
    {
        return await Task.Run(() => GetReportBytes());
    }
    
    private FileResult GetReportBytes()
    {
        // lots of CPU bound work here
    }
    
    private HttpResponseMessage CreateReportRedirectResponse()
    {
        var redirectResponse = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Moved);
        redirectResponse.Headers.Location = new Uri("<reportLocationHere>");
        return redirectResponse;
    }
```

I assume the call to `StartReportGenerationInBackground()` returns immediately, and the response is returned to the client.

What happens to the thread that was kicked off to run the `GetReportBytes()`?

Does it still run in the background even though the response was already sent back to the client?

Comment: Have you tried it with a Delay inside your background task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`new Task(...).Start();` is an unnecessarily complex way of saying `_ = Task.Run(...);`

> I assume the call to StartReportGenerationInBackground() returns immediately, and the response is returned to the client.

Yes. This is a form of "fire and forget", an attempt at a solution for returning early from HTTP requests.

> What happens to the thread that was kicked off to run the GetReportBytes()?
>
> Does it still run in the background even though the response was already sent back to the client?
>
> // concern with this new thread is that IIS could kill the process given the response will have already been returned.

Well, that's the tricky part. The code will continue running in the background. Until it doesn't.

There's nothing in ASP.NET (or IIS) that will kill this code as soon as the response returns, so the code is *allowed* to continue running. But at the same time, there's nothing in ASP.NET (or IIS) that will *keep* it running until it finishes.

More specifically, this application doesn't allow shutdowns. If the application is ever stopped, this kind of background work is discarded (without even a log message to inform you it happened). Stopping happens regularly: when deploying a new version, when scaling down, when rebooting after patch night, when IIS decides to restart periodically... And those are just the graceful restarts; there's also the rude restarts, such as hardware failures, bluescreens, and top-level app exceptions.

The bottom line is that if this app is restarted *for any reason*, all background work like this will be lost. For that reason, I would say this code is dangerous and should not be used.

There are *proper* solutions that do allow returning early from HTTP requests, most notably the [basic distributed architecture](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2021/01/asynchronous-messaging-1-basic-distributed-architecture.html) that I describe on my blog.

Comment: Wouldn't the work be discarded anyway, even if it was running synchronously? Or is there something in place to wait for HTTP requests to finish being processed before restarts happen? This code is running in an app service in Azure btw.

Comment: @DavidKlempfner, IIS/ASP.NET tries to honor all running requests and background work, provided they finish quickly (5 seconds, I think), before an App Domain is taken down.

Comment: Ignore my comment. I just read in your blog "Every HTTP server framework keeps track of how many outstanding requests it has, and considers itself “safe to shut down” when that number reaches zero".

Comment: Is `GetReportBytesAsync()` a "fake async" method? I read somewhere (I think in one of your articles) that only I/O bound processing should be async, and CPU bound is not asynchronous but parallel. What's the convention for method names that are not really async?

Comment: @DavidKlempfner: Yes, it's fake-async. There's no naming convention because fake-async methods shouldn't exist.

Comment: I just found out we're doing lots of redirects in a while loop until the report has been generated, which keeps the server from being shutdown. Obviously one of those temp solutions that became permanent.

Comment: Isn't it only fake async if you call the method SomethingAsync()?

Comment: @DavidKlempfner: A fake-async method is one that has an asynchronous signature (i.e., returns a `Task`) but is implemented by running synchronous code on a thread pool thread. Also, additional requests are insufficient to prevent shutdown.

Comment: @StephenCleary why are additional requests insufficient to prevent shutdown?

Comment: I believe the shutdown procedure is to first stop taking requests and then wait until existing requests complete. That's the way all load balancers work, at least.